# include a Module to a class with a class Method referencing to the Module to be included

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following example

```
class Test
  configure_helper
end

module ConfigureHelper
  module ClassMethods
    def configure_helper
    end
  end
end
```

ConfigureHelper has some more functionality which will extend the class with ClassMethods in which the module was included.

So the problem is, if i use the following code to include the module

```
Test.send :include, ConfigureHelper
```

The Test class will be loaded and will raise a NoMethodError for configure_helper.

Is there any way to attach the configure_helper method so that configure_helper wont be called?

Comment: Update: the class Test is not created by me, i will just provide the functionality for it. so i cant change the Test class.

I know i could to what i want by extend the Object or any other parent class of Test. But i don't really want to do this, unless its really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Why not include the module right in the class definition?

```
module ConfigureHelper
  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def configure_helper
    end
  end
end

class Test
  include ConfigureHelper

  configure_helper
end
```

Comment: I got `new1.rb:11:in `<class:Test>': undefined local variable or method `configure_helper' for Test:Class (NameError)`

Comment: Yes - Now it is Okay. Please check my answer.I can't access `configure_helper` within Test class. Why?

Comment: The Problem is, that i don't get the possibility to add the include statement, since this would be a existing class

Comment: Ruby has open classes. You can add methods (and include statements) to any class. Are you saying that already existing `Test` class already contains `configure_helper` invocation which breaks the code?

Comment: thats true. I am thinking of a gem, which adds this functionality, but dont wont to include this to every class.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
  class Test
    end

    module ConfigureHelper
      module ClassMethods
       def self.included(base)
         base.class_eval do
           def configure_helper
              p 'Yes'
           end
         end
       end
      end
    end


    Test.send(:include, ConfigureHelper::ClassMethods)

    Test.new.configure_helper
```

Comment: The case here is, that class Test doesn't call configure_helper. The class i try to extend already contains configure_helper.